# Is There an Official World Championship for Bullet Chess?

Tags: fide, tournament, world-championship, bullet-chess

I'm curious about the official status of Bullet Chess championships. While we have established world championships for classical, rapid, and blitz chess, I'm wondering if there is a similar official world championship specifically for Bullet Chess.

Bullet Chess, known for its extremely fast pace (usually 1 minute per player per game), is quite popular online, but does it have an official world championship recognized by FIDE or any other major chess organization?

Comment: Note that when the speed is extremely high, time settings for "online" and "on a physical board" become hard to compare, because tapping a square on a screen is much faster than physically grabbing a piece, moving it to another square without fumbling, and then pressing a clock. Especially since online you can "premove", which is itself a nonnegligible gain of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bullet Chess, known for its extremely fast pace (usually 1 minute per player per game), is quite popular online, but does it have an official world championship recognized by FIDE

No.

For standard rate chess the latest regulations ([FIDE Rating Regulations effective from 1 March 2024](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B022024)) say this:

> **1. Rate of Play**
>
> 1.1     For a game to be rated each player must at the start of the game have the following minimum periods in which to complete all the moves, assuming the game lasts 60 moves.
>
> Where at least one of the players in the game has a rating of 2400 or higher, each player must have a minimum of 120 minutes.
>
> Where at least one of the players in the game has a rating 1800 or higher, each player must have a minimum of 90 minutes.
>
> Where both of the players in the game are rated below 1800, each player must have a minimum of 60 minutes.

For shorter time controls the [FIDE Rapid and Blitz Rating Regulations effective from 1 March 2024](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B02RBRegulations2024) say this:

> **1. Rate of Play**
>
> 1.1     For a game to be rated each player must have the following periods in which to complete all the moves:
>
> 1.1.1      for a rapid game all the moves must be made in a fixed time of more than 10 minutes but less than 60 minutes for each player; or the time allotted + 60 times any increment must be more than 10 minutes but less than 60 minutes for each player;
>
> 1.1.2      for a blitz game all the moves must be made in a fixed time of more than 3 minutes but not more than 10 minutes for each player; or the time allotted + 60 times any increment must be more than 3 minutes but not more than 10 minutes for each player.
>
> **1.2 Games where the players have different playing times are not rated.**

So, for the moment, FIDE does not recognise time controls where the players have 3 minutes each or less.

Comment: You've highlighted 1.2, but I don't think that's related to the question at all. It's not talking about different playing times as in "different from any of the ranges specified in 1.1.x": 1.1 already dictates that such games cannot be rated. Rather it means "different from each other", i.e. the two players have different time allotments. Right?

Answer (score 5):

If you mean in the sense of a FIDE-sanctioned event, no.  OTB bullet is an awkward affair to manage given the chaos at the board it inevitably creates and thus most competitions are held online.  Lichess has [a yearly bullet event](https://lichess.org/tournament/sgTdC7Jw), and chess.com has an [annual event](https://www.chess.com/events/info/2023-bullet-chess-championship) as well.